# Pressing menu key for opening .txt file on cmd on assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, dosbox

I'm currently developing an assembly project for university, that consists of creating an menu for a maze game, but first I've to access the desired option of the menu by just pressing the key '1', then my cmd should show the content of 'Labirinto.txt' that is my maze.  I already have the key for Exit option running, but my play option that is 'JOGAR' it's not functional. I'm opening the 'Menu.txt' and printing is content on the cmd and I want to do the same for the 'maze.txt', but i don't know why. Here is my code:

```
.8086
.model small
.stack 2048h

dseg    segment para public 'data'

        Erro_Open       db      'Erro ao tentar abrir o ficheiro$'
        Erro_Ler_Msg    db      'Erro ao tentar ler do ficheiro$'
        Erro_Close      db      'Erro ao tentar fechar o ficheiro$'
        Fich1           db      'Menu.TXT',0
        Fich2           db      'Labirinto.TXT',0
        Fich3           db      'Top10.TXT', 0
        HandleFich      dw      0
        car_fich        db      ?

dseg    ends



cseg    segment para public 'code'

    assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg

LE_TECLA    PROC

        mov     ah,08h
        int     21h
        mov     ah,0
        cmp     al,0
        jne     SAI_TECLA
        mov     ah, 08h
        int     21h
        mov     ah,1

SAI_TECLA:  RET
LE_TECLA    endp

carrega_labirinto Proc

        mov     ah,3dh          ; vamos abrir ficheiro para leitura 
        mov     al,0            ; tipo de ficheiro  
        lea     dx,Fich2            ; nome do ficheiro
        int     21h         ; abre para leitura 
        ;jc      erro_abrir     ; pode aconter erro a abrir o ficheiro 
        mov     HandleFich,ax       ; ax devolve o Handle para o ficheiro 
        ;jmp     ler_ciclo
        ret

carrega_labirinto endp

carrega_top10 Proc

        mov     ah,3dh          ; vamos abrir ficheiro para leitura 
        mov     al,0            ; tipo de ficheiro  
        lea     dx,Fich3            ; nome do ficheiro
        int     21h         ; abre para leitura 
 ;       jc      erro_abrir     ; pode aconter erro a abrir o ficheiro 
 ;;       mov     HandleFich,ax     ; ax devolve o Handle para o ficheiro 
  ;      jmp     ler_ciclo
        ret
carrega_top10 endp

Main    Proc

        mov     ax,dseg
        mov     ds,ax


;abre ficheiro

        mov     ah,3dh          ; vamos abrir ficheiro para leitura 
        mov     al,0            ; tipo de ficheiro  
        lea     dx,Fich1            ; nome do ficheiro
        int     21h         ; abre para leitura 
        jc      erro_abrir      ; pode aconter erro a abrir o ficheiro 
        mov     HandleFich,ax       ; ax devolve o Handle para o ficheiro 
        jmp     ler_ciclo       ; depois de abero vamos ler o ficheiro 

erro_abrir:
        mov     ah,09h
        lea     dx,Erro_Open
        int     21h
        jmp     sair

ler_ciclo:
        mov     ah,3fh           
        mov     bx,HandleFich        
        mov     cx,1            
        lea     dx,car_fich     
        int     21h             
      jc        erro_ler        
      cmp       ax,0            ficheiro 
      je        fecha_ficheiro   
      mov     ah,02h            
      mov       dl,car_fich     
      int       21h             
      jmp       ler_ciclo       

erro_ler:
        mov     ah,09h
        lea     dx,Erro_Ler_Msg
        int     21h

fecha_ficheiro:                 ; vamos fechar o ficheiro 
        mov     ah,3eh
        mov     bx,HandleFich
        int     21h
        jnc     LER_OPCAO

        mov     ah,09h          
        lea     dx,Erro_Close
        Int     21h

LER_OPCAO:
        call LE_TECLA
    ;   cmp     ah, 1
    ;   je      ESTEND

        CMP     AL, '1' 
        JE      jogar
        CMP     AL, '2' 
        JE      TOP10
        CMP     AL, '3' 
        JE      CONFIGURAR
        CMP     AL, '4' 
        JE      SAIR
        jmp     LER_OPCAO

JOGAR:  
    ;   call carrega_labirinto      ;1
        jmp     LER_OPCAO

TOP10:  
;       call carrega_top10      ;2
        jmp     LER_OPCAO

CONFIGURAR: 
;       call carrega_configuracao       ;3
        jmp     LER_OPCAO

SAIR:   
        mov     ah,4CH
        INT     21H

Main    endp
cseg    ends
end     Main
```

Comment: Because the code for options 1, 2 and 3 has been commented out?

Comment: Even if you *do* `call carrega_labirinto` for option 1, all it does is to open a file and store the file handle - nothing more.

Comment: You will be not able to open file called `"Labirinto.txt"` with `int 21h` services this way, you need the "short" 8.3 encoded name of file (probably something like `"LABIRI~1.TXT"`. Use `dir /?` to see which command line option shows short names (I don't have windows ... actually the dosbox "dir" should work well for you). The long names are feature of Windows 95 IIRC.

Comment: @Ped7g good catch I missed that. Simplest way out is to use 8.3 filenames such as `"LABY.TXT"` or `"MAZE.TXT"`. Luis, 8.3 means maximum 8 characters for filename + maximum 3 characters for filename extension.